# Connecting the MFRC522 RFID Reader/Writer to PC

Tags: rfid

Referring to the MFRC522 RFID Reader/Writer  rfid reader writer module.
How do I configure its UART so it can talk to an rs232 port of a PC?

The answer is probably similar to this question

https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/30719/how-to-program-an-nrfl01-rf-module-that-is-connected-to-a-pc-via-a-usb-to-uart-t

which point out that it not easy to write PC software (not suprisingly) for a arduino module with same interface. So the question is then -is there an existing PC software for this?

Answer (score 2):

There's an existing [Arduino library](https://github.com/zodier/MFRC522-UART-Arduino) that uses the module's UART interface, rather than the more common SPI. It provides basic methods for reading the UID of a card and R/W operations on blocks. You could easily port that library to your favourite PC programming language, connect the module to your PC probably through some USB-UART adapter and get to work.

If your PC has an actual TIA-232 serial port and you want to use that to talk to the module, you'll need a driver like the [MAX232](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/max232.pdf) to sit between the module's TTL UART and the PC serial port.

Use this as a guide:

[image]

All GNDs must be connected together.

Comment: I am new to hardware and would like a circuit diagram. What are the circuit diagrams for the rs232 answer you mention? And yes, my desktop PC does have an RS232 port on it.

Comment: Do you need four pins rather than three for rs232 connection for this module?

Comment: Four or three pins?-what the exact circuit to interface to rs232?-I dont think the answer is that easy too

Comment: @yabbadabba You only need 3 pins for UART. See my edit.

Comment: I get the general idea of you guide solution and why an max232 maybe needed. But maybe I misunderstood something -I thought UART was not the same as RS232 -so it doesnt make sense to me to say it needs 3 pins. I thought maybe the DTR line maybe needed.

Comment: @yabbadabba DTR isnt needed for full duplex communication either with a UART or through an RS232 driver. Only TX, RX and GND. Besides I dont think you have access to DTR for the RC522 module so this is moot. Make the connections as shown.

Comment: Even after wiring the question is then the software for PC. To port the arduino code it would be rewrirting most of the library which I dont think is easy. Do you know where I can find the source code for PC?

Comment: @yabbadabba It isnt hard to port the code to Python, given the ease and abundance of examples on using Pyserial. If you want ready-made code, I suggest you google away.

Comment: Im interested in C++ rather than Python becuase C++ is more powerful language. I guess your python idea may be a starting point-though-after searching a while- ive only found lots of examples for raspberry pi python and arduino easily. The code must be out there some where becuase you said its easy. I ll make a good attempt to find it-if I do I'll add it to the answer of this question.

Comment: is there any off-the-shelf software on web for this purpose? thanks

Comment: @Saleh None that I know of. Your best bet's probably to just write some firmware on some Arduino to serve as a "middleman" between your PC and the RC522. Or you can search github to see if someone's done it already.